# API PLATFROM - Query Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.isActive

Tags: symfony, annotations, graphql

I'm facing issues with easy query to API-PLATFROM.
GraphQL Playground:

```
{
  users{
    edges{
      node{
       id
        email
      isActive
      }
    }
  }
}
```

error:
"debugMessage": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.isActive.", same error I've got  for createdAt filed.

Symfony entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Groups({"read","write"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Groups({"read","write"})
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function getIsActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive(bool $isActive): self
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Of course, I've got other getters and setters. When I change the query for example to return id and email, everything works correctly.

Comment: private $isActive = true;  Should initialize email as well.  That way your entity is always in a properly initialized state.

Comment: Thank you Ceard, for the answer but unfortunately still not work. isActive is set to true and data are loaded to the database by fixtures.

Comment: db structure checked, values for isActive set?